# How to get rectangle annotation coords in preview?

Tags: preview

[image]

How can i get the coords of this annotated rectangle in preview app or other mac app?

Comment: i ended up just using PhotoShop. but if u can select the rectangle annotations, u should be able to get their coords IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up just using PhotoShop. but if u can select the rectangle annotations, u should be able to get their coords IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a command-shift-4 (the command to do a screenshot of a selected region) your cursor turns into crosshairs and listed with the crosshairs are the x,y coordinates.